# $P(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}.$Then is it true that $a_n=0 ~\forall n\geq0~?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, power-series

Let a power series $P(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}.$Then is it true that $a_n=0 ~\forall n\geq0~?$

I faced this power series expression in a problem and I have a intuition that this might be true and I am not sure about this statement. Can anyone give me any clarification about this statement? Any counterexample or proof will be very helpful for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume the power series is convergent for any $x>0$ i.e. the radius of convergence is infinite.  Hence the series is convergent for any $x\in \mathbb{R}.$ Therefore we can extend $P(x)$ to the whole line by the same power series. Moreover  $P\in C^\infty$ and $n!a_n=P^{(n)}(0)=0.$

Comment: Indeed, even if $P(x)=0$ only on some bounded closed infinite subset of $\mathbb R,$ every coefficient is $0.$ So zeroes at $x=0,1,1/2,\dots,1/n,\dots$ is enough.

Comment: Yes... Then I can now say that this statement is correct indeed ?

Comment: By induction:

$a_0=P(0)=0$

suppose $a_0=\ldots=a_N=0$.

Then, for $x\neq0$

$$P(x)=a_{N+1}x^{N+1}+a_{N+2}x^{N+2} +\ldots=x^{N+1}\Big(a_{N+1}+a_{N+2}x+\ldots \Big)=0$$

This means that $P_{N+1}(x)=a_{N+1}+a_{N+2}x+\ldots=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. It is not difficult to show that $P_{N+1}$ is differentiable and hence continuous at $0$; hence $P_{N+1}(0)=a_{N+1}=0$.